# Hexchat not in the gnome topbar

Tags: gnome, 18.04, indicator, gnome-shell, hexchat

when I used xfce and hexchat I always saw a small icon on the top when hexchat was open. I switched to Ubuntu (Gnome) 18.04 yesterday and I don’t see it on the topbar. Why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok nevermind I found how.
You need to install [TopIcons Plus](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1031/topicons/)